# Laravel command every minute doesn't work

Tags: php, date, laravel, command, schedule

Edit:
@Bogdan, the script only executed once, which was exactly one hour before the next day would start, which is odd, also because the `start` time of both appointments on that day were different. Both appointments, however, were set for the next day.

So basically my script didn't check for upcoming appointments in the next hour, but simply for appointments that were set for tomorrow, and send an email one hour before the day those appointments would start. Confusing. Also, wouldn't the seconds matter if the time was checked in the format `Y-m-d H:i`? Or am I missing something?

OP:

I have a few commands set up using the laravel cronjob and scheduler. I have got all commands that I need working, except for one. I have an appointments database where I store a timestamp for when an appointment is due. Using a command, I want to send an e-mail one hour before the appointment is due. For that, I use the following command:

```
$schedule->command('appointment:hourly')->everyMinute();
```

So it runs every minute. In my command I have the following:

```
$date = Carbon::now()->addHours('1')->format('Y-m-d H:i');

$appointments = Appointment::latest('start')->date($date)->get();
```

So it sets the date to `now()`, then it adds an hour and checks that value in the database. My e-mails never get send (the e-mail script works since I am using that same script for my other commands).

I have tried the following as well:

```
$date = Carbon::now()->addHours('1')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Still nothing. My dates are stored in the database like so for example:

```
2016-01-25 09:00:00
```

So wether or not it also checks to match the seconds, it should work. When I check my `$date` in my view, it does return `2016-01-25 09:00` for example.

Any pointers will be glady appreciated.

Btw, my `date()` function. It just checks the value against the `start` column:

```
public function scopeDate($query, $date)
{
    if($date)
    {
        return $query->whereDate('start', '=', $date);
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

PS. One thing I should mention. Last night at exactly 11:00 PM, I got two e-mails from the above command, saying an appointment was set to start in an hour from now. Those were appointments that were set to start for today, but they were not set to start at 00:00. So I guess with the above command, it doesn't check for appointments for today. I got confused and haven't been able to figure this out just yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to consider here:

**1.** Make sure your have the correct timezone set in your `config/app.php` file, as that might be the cause of the appointment notification email being sent at the wrong time.

**2.** From the time the cron job runs until the `Carbon::now()` statement is executed, the time might not be exactly what you expect it to be (this is not a certainty and is something that can be affected by what your code does and/or the server load at the time of the execution). So the time might be `09:00:01` instead of `09:00:00`, in which case your condition would not be true anymore (this being another reason why it worked sporadically).

To make sure the time difference doesn't affect the condition you should check if the time is **one hour or less** from the current time, this would of course require you to set some sort of *marker* that lets you know if the notification was sent. Also since `whereDate` only compares the date part of the date and time string, there is the need to handle checking the time as well. Since Eloquent doesn't offer any methods for that, you can use the [`hour`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour) and [`minute`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_minute) MySQL function in conjunction with `whereRaw` like so:

```
$date = Carbon::now()->addHours('1');

$query->where('notified', false)
      ->whereDate('start', '=', $date->format('Y-m-d'))
      ->whereRaw('hour(start) <= ?', [$date->format('H')])
      ->whereRaw('minute(start) <= ?', [$date->format('i')]);
```

Comment: "To make sure the time difference doesn't affect the condition you should check if the time is one hour or less from the current time". That makes perfect sense indeed and I will be sure that it will work. As for my scope, I use it like that because I also use that scope in my view, and it works perfectly. if I use it like you say, my view doesn't work anymore if nothing is passed to the scope.

Comment: Edited the OP to briefly explain some things because comments are not the way to go for that imo :D

Comment: Just did some more testing, and I added a few records where the time was the exact date including the current hour and minutes, plus the seconds. Did a few tests with refreshing and nothing was pulled from the database. So something is wrong and I will figure it out :) My correct timezone is set in the app.php btw. I think because whereDate only checks against dates, and when time is added in the mix, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: You are correct that `whereDate` only checks the date and not the time, so I've updated the answer with a solution for that. Also not that this is clear, it makes perfect sense why it worked at 11:00 PM. That's because adding an hour transformed the current date and time from 11:00 PM "today" to 00:00 AM "tomorrow" and so the condition was true since both entires had the `start` date set for the next day (time was not compared so both entries were matched).

Comment: Yeah and that just hit me as well :) And I just had to grab my phone to see if I was right. Back to sleep now and I will fix this issue and accept your answer soon :) Thanks!